# Substitute the remaining part of line after pattern matching with input from user

Tags: bash

I am looking for bash command that matches the pattern in file and substitutes the remaining part of the line with the input which the script asks the user.Is something like that possible in the bash script?

For example :I have file which is input file for another program.I wish to change parts of it using bash script.

```
karyotype ='red.txt'
chromosomes_units = 1000000


<ideogram>

<spacing>
default = 0.001r
</spacing>

radius    = 0.9r
thickness = 20p
fill      = yes
```

So,is it possible that I can search 'karyotype = ' using grep/sed command and change the remaining part of line based on user prompt.For example,I wish to change the red.txt to any file name provided by user.

Comment: Can you add an example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` for this:

```
# user input string
str='foo.bar'

# use sed for replacement
sed -i.bak "s~^\( *karyotype *= *\).*$~\1'$str'~" input

# check results
cat input
karyotype ='foo.bar'
chromosomes_units = 1000000


<ideogram>

<spacing>
default = 0.001r
</spacing>

radius    = 0.9r
thickness = 20p
fill      = yes
```

Alternatively you can use this safer `awk` when you don't know value of `str` beforehand:

```
awk -v str="'a&b'" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1=="karyotype "{$2=str} 1' file
```

Comment: Try testing with `str='a&b'` and `str='a~b'`.